# React: props are undefined, even though they should be

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, react-props

my props in the children class is supposed to be an array of Event objects.

I am checking beforehand, if the array is empty in App.js like this:

```
function App() {

  class Event {
    constructor(id, title, date){
      this.id = id;
      this.title = title;
      this.date = date;
    }
  }

  const [events, setEvents] = useState([])
  const [ids, setIds] = useState([])
  const [safedIds, setSafedIds] = ([])
  const [eventsPrep, setEventsPrep] = useState([Event])

  useEffect(() => {
      fetch('https://someAPI.com')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(
        res => {setEvents(res); 
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
      .then(handleIncomingData())
      //.then(console.log("was here"))
  }, [])

  function handleIncomingData () {
    if(events.length > 0) {
      events.forEach(event => {
        ids.push(event["_id"]);
        let date = new Date(event["date"]);
        eventsPrep.push(new Event(event["_id"], event["title"], date.toDateString()))
      })
    } 
  }

  return (
    <>  
      <Navbar/>
      {eventsPrep.length > 0 ? <Home events={eventsPrep}/> : <></>}
    </>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

but whenever I try to reach the props in the child component it is considered undefined.

My child component:

```
import React from 'react'
import SingleEvent from '../../event/SingleEvent'


export const Home = (props) => {
    console.log(props.events)
    return (
        <>
          {props?.events
            ? props.events.forEach((event) => {
                console.log('was here 2');
                return <SingleEvent title={event.title} start={event.date} />;
              })
            : 'no upcomming events'}
        </>
    );
  
}
```

Even if I only pass a string down, it is still undefined.

Thanks for help!

Comment: `eventsPrep > 0` is not how you check if an array is empty, you should check the length `eventsPrep.length > 0`

Comment: Using `return` in a `.forEach()` loop doesn't do much that is useful in your code. You probably wanted to use `.map()` and use that in your `return`ed JSX.

Comment: Still when I log props.events it is undefined. So the main question is why it doesn't recognizes the array.

Comment: How do you set `eventsPrep`?

Comment: Uploaded the whole class. When I log the eventsPrep in App it is never empty.

Comment: Your'e modifying the `eventsPrep` state directly. You should treat your state values as read only (ie: immutable) and not change them using methods like `.push()`. You need to create a new array rather than pushing with `eventsPrep.push()`, and call  `setEventsPrep()` with that new array.

Comment: In your title, what do you mean by:  _even though they should be_ ?  Did you mean to write: _shouldn't be_?

Answer (score 0):

In your `useEffect()` you update `events` via `setEvents(res)` and  call `handleIncomingData()` after that.

In `handleIncomingData()` you use `events`, but it will still hold the value from previous render / from the initialization as `setEvents(res)` will not change `events` immidiately. You can `console.log(events)` inside that function to investigate this.
Instead you can pass `res` into `handleIncomingData()` and use it instead of `events` inside that function. So in you `useEffect` you would have:

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(
    res => {
      setEvents(res); 
      handleIncomingData(res);
    })
```

In addition in `handleIncomingData()` use `setEventsPrep(...)` instead of `eventsPrep.push()`, as mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score -1):

You are returning 2 return statements in the component. Only need to return 1 return statement in component

```
export const Home = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      {props?.events && Object.values(props.events).length > 0
        ? props.events.forEach((event) => {
            console.log('was here 2');
            return <SingleEvent title={event.title} start={event.date} />;
          })
        : 'no upcoming events'}
    </>
  );
};
```

Also to check whether eventsPrep has a length > 0  then try it this way if eventsPrep is an object

```
eventsPrep && Object.values(eventsPrep).length > 0
```

Comment: That doesn't change the fact, that props is still undefined.